# Ошибка , при невалид прокси . Golang

Tags: golang

я отправляю запрос на сайт с подключенной прокси и все работает , но в случае мертвой прокси я получаю ошибку.

```
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x38 pc=0x42c65e]

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    z:/main.go:33 +0x3de
exit status 2
Process exiting with code: 1 signal: false
```

как обработать данную ошибку ?

мой код:

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "strings"

    "golang.org/x/net/proxy"
)

func main() {
    dialer, err := proxy.SOCKS5("tcp", strings.TrimSpace("212.129.25.12:21418"), nil, proxy.Direct)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error connecting to proxy:", err)
    }
    client := &http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            Dial: dialer.Dial,
        },
    }

    requestBody, err := json.Marshal(map[string]string{
        "api":         strings.TrimSpace("login"),
        "key": "CrES3B2kN0k2VJsras5W",
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ошибка")
    }
    req, err := client.Post("https://httpbin.org/#/Auth", "application/json", bytes.NewBuffer(requestBody))
    req.Header.Set("content-type", "application/json")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ошибка")
    }
    defer req.Body.Close()
    // resposnse decode
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(req.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ошибка")
    }
    fmt.Println(string(body))
}
```

Comment: Вы же в курсе, что после `fmt.Println` выполнение программы идёт дальше?

Comment: как я понимаю , перед ошибкой я должен получить сообщение Error connecting to proxy: . но такого не проиходит

Comment: А ещё у вас путаница, где запрос, а где ответ.  `client.Post` возвращает **ответ**, причём вы пытаетесь **ответу** установить заголовок **до** того, как проверяете ошибку.

Comment: я совсем новичек, был бы очень рад если бы вы помогли мне составить правильный код .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположу, что проблема здесь:

```golang
req, err := client.Post("https://httpbin.org/#/Auth", "application/json", bytes.NewBuffer(requestBody))
req.Header.Set("content-type", "application/json")
if err != nil {
	fmt.Println("ошибка")
}
```

Во-первых, это `resp`,
а не `req`. Ответ,
а не запрос. Во-вторых, вы используете `req`
до того, как проверяете `err`. Лучше
как-то так:

```sh
resp, err := client.Post("https://httpbin.org/#/Auth", "application/json", bytes.NewBuffer(requestBody))
if err != nil {
	fmt.Println("ошибка")
}

// Работа с resp.
```

Comment: действительно , ошибка заключалась в req.Header.Set("content-type", "application/json") , удалил эту строку и обработчик ошибок заработал ) спасибо!